# What does this mean? - help with 続き and なら

Tags: translation, meaning, nouns, renyōkei

> 日本語で[続]{つづ}きをよむならてつだいますよ！
>   [続]{つづ}きをよんでほしいです

I'm confused about tsuzuki and nara. Going by it's definition of continuation... it doesn't really make much sense to me plus the conditional...

I get the sentence in essence is her wanting to help me learn to read but I don't properly understand it.

The context is; she is a penpal and is responding to a comment I made about why I want to learn to read Japanese.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe writing it out with all needed Kanjis would help:

> 日本語で続きを読むなら手伝いますよ！

"If you read the rest in Japanese then I will lend you a hand."

With this, in the next sentence, she's saying:

> 続きを読んでほしいです。

"I want you to read the rest."

**Some points:**

続き： Remember that this is a noun, not a verb, meaning the remaining, the following, the continuation, etc.

なら： This is the conditional, as you mentioned.

**More breakdown:**

読む: To read

続きを読む: Read the remaining

日本語で続きを読む: Read the remaining in Japanese

日本語で続きを読むなら: If you read the remaining in Japanese

... etc.